# Square bracket during setting a value in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am new to Angular and Typescript, I came across below code:

```
export enum LayoutActionTypes {
  OpenSidenav = '[Layout] Open Sidenav',
  CloseSidenav = '[Layout] Close Sidenav',
}
```

I am trying to google it out but I am not getting any relevant results. Whats does  [] do in setting the value ? What's its significance. I can guess that it is used to group these values under `Layout`.

Comment: I guess it depends on how they're being used, but most likely those are just strings to aid debugging. The square brackets don't do anything besides tag the message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of square brackets in the enum declaration in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48073719/what-is-the-meaning-of-square-brackets-in-the-enum-declaration-in-typescript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We see a set of actions defined here. Actions in angular are just strings.

The square brackets have no syntactical meaning.

There is just a **convention** in angular ngrx that action names start with a category name in square brackets where actions that are related to each other use the same category name.